# Confusion regarding the definition of addition modulo $n$ on the group $Z_n$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, modular-arithmetic, binary-operations

Consider the group $Z_n$$= \{[0],[1],[2],...,[n-1]\}$. Where the elements of $Z_n$ are equivalence classes, and $Z_n$ is a partition of the integers. So, to me I understand it as: If $[r]$ belongs to $Z_n$, then $[r]$ contains all the integers that have a reminder -when divided by n- of $r\pmod n$. Notice the reminder is not just r, it's $r\pmod n$, to guarantee that the notation $ [r] $ still make sense when    $r>n$. Then the definition of addition modulo n is: $[a]+[b] = [a+b]$. Which means that if you add the set with the elements of reminder $a\pmod n$ with the set of the elements with the reminder $b\pmod n$ you get the set of the elements with reminder of $(a+b)\pmod n$, which make sense.

But the problem is that I see books define $[r]$ to mean: the set of numbers with reminder $r$. And then they define $[a]+[b]=[a+b]$. But the problem is $a+b$ could be bigger than $n$, so under this definition of $[r]$, $[a+b]$ means the set of numbers with reminder $a+b$, which doesn't make sense when $a+b>n$. So which is the correct definition of the operation addition modulo n in the context of abstract algebra ?

Comment: If r> n, then n=r mod n is meaningless ! isn't it ?

Comment: Sorry, I expressed that carelessly: $[r]=\{m\in\mathbb{Z}:m=r\bmod n\}$

Comment: Still what is [n+1] under your definition ? it's undefined, there is no number that when you divide it by n gives you a reminder of n+1. That is the thing that I'm asking about ... defining [r] this way doesn't allow you to talk about numbers bigger than n, since r must be less than n to be reminder !

Comment: Ah! You misunderstand the definition of $a=b\bmod n$. It means that $a-b$ is divisible by $n$. Forget about remainders, that is not really a helpful way to think about it.

Comment: It's really useful to use the notation $\Bbb Z/n\Bbb Z$ instead of $\Bbb Z_n$ which can have other meanings.  Also, an easily intuitive example of modular addition is the time in hours given by $\Bbb Z/12\Bbb Z$. Once you get to 13 o'clock, that's 1 o'clock on a 12 hour clock.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, both are correct. If $a,b$ are integers, the addition mod $n$ is defined as
$$[a]+[b] = [a+b]$$
where $[a+b]$ is the congruence or residue class mod $n$. So if $a+b$ is not a remainder mod $n$, a number from $0$ to $n-1$, then divide $a+b$ by $n$ with remainder:
$a+b =qn+r$, where $0\leq r<n$, and so $$[a+b]=[r].$$

There are two basic facts to use:

(1) Each integer $a$ lies in the same residue class as its remainder $r$ mod $n$, i.e., if $a=qn+r$ with $0\leq r<n$, then $[a]=[r]$.

(2) For distinct remainders $r,r'$ mod $n$, the residue classes are distinct, i.e., $[r]\ne[r']$.

Comment: I see, but my only problem is that if you define [r] to mean: the set of numbers with reminder r. Then [n+1] for example is meaningless there is no reminder of n+1. So I feel that it's wrong to say that [r] means the set of numbers with reminder r, it must be with reminder r(modn). But almost all books  I have seen do it the former way, which I can't understand why !

Comment: No, $[n+1]=[1]$.

Comment: I know but that is true under my definition of [n+1], not under the definition that is given in most books ! Is it sensible to talk about reminder of n+1 when dividing by n?

Comment: $n+1 = 1\cdot n +1$ with remainder $1$.

Comment: @yousefmagableh Yes. Your definition is simply wrong!

Comment: When you wrote $a+b=an+r$, did you mean $\color{red}qn+r$?

Comment: Indeed, $a+b=qn+r$, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

$r$, is simply one of infinitely many representatives of the set of numbers with remainder $r$ on division by $n$. So $a+b$ is just another representative of the set of numbers that have the same remainder as it on division by $n$. We typically use the lowest value, to symbolize the set, but it need not be. We can write any number with the same remainder, as  along division that doesn't completely take every $n$ away at the end.

Comment: But in the case of [a+b] we cant say it's the set of numbers with reminder of a+b. Since a+b could be bigger than n. That was my concern, but it had answered in the comments, and I did had the wrong definition for the meaning of [k].

Comment: how do you tell 2 hours after 11 is 1 ...

Comment: I get your point ( 13=1 mod 12 ), but I had a wrong definition for what that means in my question and it had been corrected by @almagest.